# Select Rows with Same Id but different Values in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I know this is possible in database software but is there any way to do it in Python Pandas?

```
ID1         ID2      Value
1209345     1203     2
1209345     1204     3 <-----
1209345     1205     4
1209345     1203     2
1209345     1204     7 <-----
1209346     1203     1
1209347     1204     5
```

I have `ID1` and, corresponding to that, I have multiple `ID2`s mapped with a value. I need to find all entries where `ID1` and `ID2` are matching but the values are different.

My current code counts the number of unique combinations of `ID1` and `ID2`, but does not account for unique `Value` for each combination:

```
print(df.groupby(['ID1', 'ID2']).size())

ID1      ID2 
1209345  1203    2
         1204    2
         1205    1
1209346  1203    1
1209347  1204    1
dtype: int64
```

**Note:** This question is posted for @RohitGirdhar who deleted his [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50581614/select-rows-with-same-id-but-different-values-in-pandas). The solution I post is not necessarily the only or best one; other answers are encouraged.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can filter with [`nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nunique.html) and [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html):

```
df = df[df.groupby(['ID1', 'ID2'])['Value'].transform('nunique') > 1]

print (df)
       ID1   ID2  Value
1  1209345  1204      3
4  1209345  1204      7
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to `groupby` to `set`, filter the resulting series, and then filter your original dataframe by combination of `ID1` & `ID2`:

```
grps = df.groupby(['ID1', 'ID2'])['Value'].apply(set)
filtered = grps[grps.map(len) > 1].index

res = df[df.set_index(['ID1', 'ID2']).index.isin(filtered)]

print(res)

       ID1   ID2  Value
1  1209345  1204      3
4  1209345  1204      7
```