# Pandas Identifying records with matching value in one column but not another

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I specifically need to find rows where the 'col1_x' value matches the same column value of another row, AND the row it matched with has a different 'col1_y' value.

I'm kind of stumped.

Base Set

```
   col1_x   col2  col1_y
0       1   brad      37
1       2    tom      55
2       3    tom      55
3       2  sally      28
```

Expected Result

```
   col1_x   col2  col1_y
1       2    tom      55
3       2  sally      28
```

Comment: Your question needs some clarification. How did you filter out 0th row?

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
The basics of matching (or not) are covered in many examples and tutorials, so we want to work with your actual coding attempt.

Comment: @Inputvector: Rows 0 and 2 do not match any other row's `x` column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I specifically need to find rows where the 'col1_x' value matches the same column value of another row,

This can be done by finding duplicates

> AND the row it matched with has a different 'col1_y' value.

This can be done by finding *not* duplicates. Something like this should work:

```
df[(df.col1_x.duplicated(keep=False))&(~df.col1_y.duplicated())]
```

Comment: Later found the thing that best represents what I needed.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50583828/select-rows-with-same-id-but-different-values-in-pandas

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:

```
df.loc[df['col1_x'].duplicated(keep='first') | df['col2'].duplicated(keep='last') ]

#Output: 

col1_x  col2    col1_y
1   2   tom     55
3   2   sally   28
```